# TextAreaFor not displaying default CSS style in asp net mvc

Tags: css, asp.net

It seems that ASP NET MVC is having problem to display the correctly when I use TextAreaFor. Is anyone there having this problem?

[This is how the browser is displaying it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAl0M.png)

Notice that the last TextArea is being displayed just fine.

[This is how the code is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bCTY.png)

Notice that the TextArea below* the red retangular is being displayed just fine.

**Answer**

```
    textarea
    {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: #555555;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
        -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 
         0.15s;
        transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Seano666, I don't know why when I use TextAreaFor on asp net mvc the CSS class "form-control" don't work.

Comment: You haven't posted any CSS code.  What happens when you inspect the TextArea in the browser developer tools.  Does it have the CSS class that you expect?

Comment: I saw a difference between both TextArea, but this html/css code is generated by Razor. Sorry I can't post the full css that I'm using because it has more than 6k lines.  i.stack.imgur.com/8tL9Z.png @Seano666

Comment: This is a better view of the generated HTML code,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPScn.png

Comment: Thank for you help. I added the following code in the end of the question and aparently solved my problem with this component @Seano666

Comment: What was the issue with your CSS?

Comment: Yes, the default CSS generated by VS2015 has a bug. Even though I thought it was something to do with how Razor as generating the CSS. @Seano666

Answer (score 2):

I think you typoed the TextAreaFor:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Titulo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Should be

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Titulo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

or even

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Titulo, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks for you help @Frank Witte, but my problem was with the default CSS of ASP NET MVC Application gerenerated for VisualStudio.